# Is there a place to dispute duplicate markings?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

My question was marked as a duplicate, and I have some issues to point out about it. I was wondering if there was a place to go to dispute the marking?

This would be really useful, as I am now losing reputation points for what I feel is an incorrect marking.

Comment: Thanks @polygeo, I couldn't find that when I searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disagree with your post being closed as a duplicate, *just edit it*. Edits bump it to the homepage and it will be reopened if enough users agree that it's not a duplicate. If you have 250 reputation, you can also vote to reopen it.